# How to get feature geometry?

Tags: openlayers-2, wfs, geoext

I want to have a gridPanel with feature geometry. But I can't image how to do this. I have a `FeatureStore`

```
st = new GeoExt.data.FeatureStore({
    layer: myVecLayer,
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'mydata', type: 'String'}
    ],
    proxy: new GeoExt.data.ProtocolProxy({
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version: "1.0.0",
            srsName:"EPSG:900913",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "filedata_temp",
            featureNS: "http://www.opengeospatial.net/cite",
            filter:Ffilter
        })
    }),
    autoLoad: true
});
```

How do you get the feature geometry (with separate `X` and `Y`) from this?

I know that I'm going to get WKT from `FeatureStore` and parse it to get the coordinates, but what next, use another store to hold the coordinates?

Comment: can u give some explanation that you want to get geometry of your objects when clicking or another way? which way u want to get geometry?

Comment: Object selected by filter and in FeatureStore only one feature. Select without map clicking. I want get geometry to edit it in grid.

Comment: I use this.1 get WKT from feature. 2 Parse it in string array. 3 Add this data to Ext.ArrayStore. 3 Add store to grid. Maybe geoext has standart methods to work with geometry?